# Is it possible to update advertising data on the fly using bluez api?

Tags: linux, bluetooth-lowenergy, embedded-linux, bluez

I'm searching for a while how to update on the fly the service data or manufacturer data payload of the advertising packet.
So far, I've seen that it's possible on some microcontrollers but nothing on Linux using the Python implantation of bluez api.
Does anyone have already done this?